# Object Required error when I clearly have an object

Tags: excel, vba

Have searched and have come up short on any solutions to this. I am relatively new to VB for the record. The variable minDate here is declared in the module outside of the procedure. I have tried declaring it inside the procedure, using set, let, and passing the argument as a range variable. Nothing.

```
Sub SocialTimeSinceFirstComment()
'
' SocialTimeSinceFirstComment Macro
'
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(SocialTransform!C[4])"

    minDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Workbook.SocialTransform!.Range("c4").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: `Workbook.SocialTransform!` looks suspect.

Comment: Also: using Min() on a single cell...

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197075/why-is-a-fundemental-mis-understanding-of-code-requirements-deemed-a-typo-and-of). Please direct comments about its on-topicness there.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have a worsheet named SocialTransform so use this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SocialTransform")

Dim minRange as Range
set minRange = ws.range(ws.Range("c4"), ws.Range("c4").End(xlDown))
minRange.Select 'use this when testing so you can see exactly what is included

minDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(minRange)
```

Hopefully you have minDate declared as a date `Dim MinDate As Date` otherwise you'll just get a number; which could of course be transformed back to the corresponding date.

Also I might explain that the error you got was not because of `minDate` but because `SocialTransform!`  is not an object of `Workbook`. You need to use `Worksheets("SocialTransform")`

EDIT: Actually you can use the code name to reference a sheet within the workbook like this: `Debug.Print Sheet1.Name`

[image: Code name example]

In this example the user renamed the first sheet to "Data" and the `Sheet1.Name` will return "Data". The only way to change the code name is by change the "(Name)" property in the VBA editor window.

See: [Worksheet.CodeName Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear, and you don't "clearly have an object". (The compiler is *almost always* more aware of the code and syntax than we are, so if it says something is wrong you should probably believe it until you can prove otherwise.)

`Workbook.SocialTransform!.Range` in the last line of code you posted is invalid (`WOrkbook.SocialTransform!` isn't valid code the way you're using it), and therefore it doesn't return an object. However, you're referencing it as one, which generates the error.

It's valid inside quotes as you're using it in the line that precedes it.